# Download multiple files using wget which has perticular pattern in the link

Tags: shell-script

I want to download the text files for all of the strains from http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php , there are 3 types of text files associated with each starin. Out of which I only want to download all strains text files with "quality_variant", I don't want quality_variant_filtered and Unsequenced, I tried multiple options with wget and grep. Unsuccessful, plz suggest,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If it is about finding the URLs (or other data) on webpages, it is called "web scraping". You mentioned you tried using `wget` and `grep` to do that, do you have any examples of script you tried? What did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you're faster when you do stuff manually. Run this in `bash`:

```
names=( Aa_0 Abd_0 Ag_0 Ak_1 Alst_1 Altai_5 Amel_1 An_1 Ang_0 Anholt_1 Ann_1
 Anz_0 Appt_1 Ba_1 Baa_1 Bch_1 Bd_0 Benk_1 Ber Bg_2 Bik_1 Bl_1 Bla_1 Boot_1
 Bor_1 Bor_4 Br_0 Bs_1 Bsch_0 Bu_0 Buckhorn_Pass CIBC_17 CIBC_5 Ca_0 Cal_0
 Cerv_1 Chat_1 Chi_0 Cnt_1 Co Co_1 Com_1 Cvi_0 Da1_12 Db_1 Dem_4 Di_G Dja_1
 Do_0 Dr_0 DraIII_1 DraII_1 Dra_0 Duk Durh_1 Ei_2 El_0 Ema_1 En_1 En_2 En_D
 Er_0 Es_0 Est Et_0 Etna_2 Fi_0 Fr_2 Ga_0 Ge_0 Gel_1 Gie_0 Gifu_2 Got_22
 Got_7 Gr_1 Gre_0 Gu_0 Gy_0 HR_10 HR_5 HSm Ha_0 Hau_0 Hey_1 Hh_0 Hn_0 Hod
 Hs_0 In_0 Is_0 Je_0 Jl_3 Jm_0 Kar_1 Kas_1 Kas_2 Kb_0 Kelsterbach_4 Kent
 Kil_0 Kin_0 Kl_5 Knox_10 Knox_18 Ko_2 Koln Kondara Kro_0 Krot_0 Kyoto Kz_9
 LL_0 La_0 Lan_0 Le_0 Li_2:1 Lip_0 Lisse Litva Lm_2 Lp2_2 Lp2_6 Mc_0 Mh_0
 Mir_0 Mnz_0 Ms_0 Mv_0 Mz_0 NC_6 NFA_10 NFA_8 N13 Nc_1 Neo_6 Nok_3 Np_0
 Nw_0 Nz_1 Ob_0 Old_1 Or_0 Ove_0 PHW_2 PHW_34 Per_1 Pi_0 Pla_0 Pna_17 Pog_0
 Pro_0 Pt_0 Pu2_23 Pu2_7 Pu2_8 Qar_8a RRS_7 RRs_10 Ra_0 Ragl_1 Rak_2 Rd_0
 Ren_1 Ren_11 Rennes_1 Rhen_1 Rld_1 Rmx_A02 Rmx_A180 Rome_1 Rou_0 Rubeznhoe_1
 Sap_0 Se_0 Seattle_0 Sei_0 Sf_1 Sg_1 Si_0 Sorbo Sp_0 Sq_1 Sq_8 Stw_0 Su_0
 Sus_1 Ta_0 Tamm_2 Tamm_27 Tha_1 Ting_1 Tol_0 Ts_1 Ts_5 Tscha_1 Tu_0 Tul_0
 Ty_0 Uk_1 Uod_1 Uod_7 Utrecht Van_0 Ven_1 Vind_1 Wa_1 Wc_1 Wei_0 Westkar_4
 Wil_1 Wl_0 Ws_2 Wt_5 Yo_0 Zal_1 Zdr_1 )
 
for i in "${names[@]}"; do
  wget "http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/data/Salk/quality_variant_${i}.txt"
done
```

Comment: thank you so much but how did you get the list of strain name? @Freddy

Comment: Copy & paste the corresponding table entries into an editor and saved it as `file`. Then run `echo $(cut -f1 file)` to get the first column entries space separated.